# Process launch failed: timed out trying to launch app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

XCode show this alert when the app is launch:

```
"Could not launch "app". Process launch failed: timed out trying to launch app"
```

I checked code signing in Project & Targets with two different approchs:
- setting the value by default like in Apple documentation
- choosing for Debug : iPhone Developer:name(...)

None of them works.
Do you have idea that comes from where and how to deal with?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could it be your app is just big or slow to start and your machine rather slow? Seen that error in such a setup ...

Comment: delete -> create -> refresh(xcode) all (appId, certifiates, provisioning profiles).